# How to change and update the tree data structure of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

How should I update the data structure tree of Apache IoTDB? For example a second-level unit, it was initially listed under first-level unit A, and now I want it to link to first-level unit B. Can I change the structure directly, or do I need to migrate historical data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do migration of the original unit in Apache IoTDB. There is a MigrationExample in the source code of IoTDB, and you can refer to that example as the migration process.